# How to create variable that clusters by order in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a vector from 1 to 200, how would I create a variable that creates an ordered cluster of these numbers. Example would be that the first 10 numbers would be assigned a 1, the next 10 would be assigned a 2, etc.

Comment: `round(Vector/10)+1` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rep`  with the `each` argument. Substitute the length of your vector for 200 and the number wanted in each group for 10 respectively, and truncate if you aren't dividing into even groups.

```r
rep(1:(200/10), each = 10)
#>   [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3
#>  [24]  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5
#>  [47]  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
#>  [70]  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10
#>  [93] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12
#> [116] 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14
#> [139] 14 14 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 17
#> [162] 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19
#> [185] 19 19 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>